# How to set a black background

Tags: vim

I cannot figure out how to set the background color to black in Vim. I am running Vim from Mac OS X 10.5.8's Terminal.app (does this mean that I am using MacVim?).

My `.gvimrc` file looks like this:

```
syntax on
set background = dark
```

All this appears to accomplish is to make text more bold than before.

Doing things like

```
:highlight Normal guibg=Black
```

in Vim doesn't seem to do anything either.

Also should I have anything in my `.vimrc` file? I am not sure which configuration file is relevant to the Vim that is automatically installed on Mac OSX (that is accessible with the `vim` command at the terminal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Terminal.app you are not using MacVim. MacVim is a standalone gVim package for mac.

To change the background to be black you need to change Terminal.app's Preferences.

Go to Preferences -> Settings and choose Pro under profiles on the left. (Or create your own profile that has a black background.)

Also those commands should be in `.vimrc` instead of `.gvimrc`. To understand the difference of the two type `:h vimrc` and `:h gvimrc` in vim.

Comment: I'm using iTerm2v3 and this was exactly the issue.  I had to edit the profile for the running session and change the black color to a true black.  With that confirmed I changed the main profile and all now black is black.

Answer (score 8):

Well, technically, it is very possible to use MacVim in a terminal. I do that everyday and it works great!

But you are using Mac OS X's default Vim in a terminal. Since it's not a GUI version of Vim, it won't read your `~/.gvimrc` and it won't apply `:hi Normal guibg=black` for obvious reasons.

Settings for CLI Vim and general settings should go into `~/.vimrc`, leaving `~/.gvimrc` for GUI-specific settings.

To get a black background in CLI Vim, type the following in normal mode:

```
:hi Normal ctermbg=black
```

To persist this setting, add the same line (without the `:`) to your `~/.vimrc`, preferably after any `colorscheme` command.

Depending on the colorscheme you are using, `Normal` may not be the only place where to do that change.

Comment: Thank you for your thoroughness.